# Datetimepicker só funciona no Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image: When click just open this popup]
[image: When click on popup it slide up and doesnt show the calendar]

Quando clicar, basta abrir este pop-up. IMG1

Ao clicar no pop-up, ele desliza para cima e não mostra o calendário. IMG2 Quando altero o boostrap para a versão 3.x.x, ele funciona corretamente.

Mas todo o meu projeto está usando a versão 4.3.1.

Alguma sugestão?

```js
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: "04/09/2019",
    locale: 'pt-br'
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- ... -->


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">




</head>


<div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker5'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 20px;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- Page JS Code -->

<script src="assets/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/simplebar.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/jquery-scrollLock.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/jquery.appear.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/plugins/moment/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="./js/atend_os.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tenho uma sugestão! Use um plugin que foi feito para o BS4, e não um plugin do BS3 dentro do BS4 ;)

Comment: Opa, to revirando a internet e não encontro algo específico do datetimepicker para o BS4

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema é que várias classe e data atributes do BS3 são diferentes do BS4, inclusive um tem o popper.js e o outro não. São várias diferenças entre as versões, não vou aborda-las aqui, mas o fato é que não é possível usar os plugins do BS3 no BS4.

Aqui tem um modelo feito para o BS4 que pode te ajudar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>



    <div class="container">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
language: "pt-BR",
orientation: 'auto',
});
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: o mesmo serve para o datetimepicker?

Comment: @FelipeFernandes acredito que não... vc tem que consultar a documentação desse plugin para ver o que tem disponível lá... Esse ai da resposta é bem completo. Aqui tem a documentação completa dele https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: valeu pela dica!.